# What percentage of NBA games had at least 2 guards from the same team post at least 10 rebounds each?

Tags: trivia, basketball, statistics, nba

Ricky Rubio and Donovan Mitchell of the Utah Jazz had 11 rebounds each during Game 3 of the first round of the 2018 NBA playoffs against the Oklahoma City Thunder. Rubio and Mitchell are guards (Rubio is a point guard and Mitchell is a shooting guard), a position in which rebounding is not part of their main responsibilities. Thus, seeing 2 guards of the same team with double digit rebounds is rare.

What percentage of NBA games, since the 2000 season, had at least 2 guards from the same team post at least 10 rebounds each?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There have only been **62 games** since the 2000-01 season, including playoffs, in which 2 guards on the same team both got 10+ rebounds. In that time, there were a total of 23,163 games played, so that gives us **~0.27%** of games.

I found this by using [this Basketball-Refernce search](http://bkref.com/tiny/8PQBO), which pulled up all the times that a guard got 10+ rebounds in a game since 2000-01. Then, I copied the results to Excel and looked to see how many times two guards on the same team (and on the same day) both got 10+ rebounds. There were 62 games which fit the criteria.

[I used this search to find how many games have been played in that time span.](http://bkref.com/tiny/EXuSe)

Here is a table of all the games it happened in:

[image]